# Calculating the permitivity of PCBs

Tags: capacitor, dielectric

I've read that the permitivity of FR-4 is around 4.5, however I would like to measure the permitivity of an actual double sided copper clad board, the way I am thinking is to measure the thickness of the substrate and calculate the capacitance of a parallel plate capacitor with air between it, then measure the capacitance of the copper clad board by attaching electrodes to either side using a good LCR meter. The ratio between the measured value and the calculated value should give me the relative permitivity.

Im not looking for extreme precision here.

What do you guys suggest?

Comment: The basic methodology seems good to me. The relative permittivity of FR4 (and most dielectrics) depends on frequency. Just keep that in mind. Also, it may not be necessary to actually measure it because there is already a lot of effort put into this problem. If you are doing it for fun or to satisfy basic curiosity then go for it. I think that is a great thing to do.

Comment: LCR meters usually measure at 100kHz or less, so you are not going to be making the reading at realistic frequencies for impedance matching. The LCR meter, if a good one, should give  you an idea of the loss tangent. If you care about other directions, they may be quite different from the Z direction (what you are measuring).

Comment: As another side note, what is sometimes done in industry is that coupons are added to the PCB design. A coupon (in this context) is a trace whose sole purpose is to allow easy measurement of characteristic impedance for validation. The trace geometry of the coupon would be the same as the trace geometry of the actual traces whose impedance you are trying to validate.

Comment: @mkeith I have an LCR meter with 100KHz max frequency, how much extrapolation up to say 1GHz can be done? without that much change. I want to do some high-frequency circuits with standard FR-4, I don't want nor have availability of specialized dielectrics such as the ones by Rogers, I would like to have a better estimate of the permitivity rather than using the 4.5 that its stated in many places. Just to note, this is not for a serious application, purely educational. How do Rogers corp, or similar measure the permitivity at high-frequncies? How is the Z0 of the coupon measured? a TDR?

Comment: I am not an RF guru. But bluetooth and wifi antenna traces are routinely implemented on FR4. It is no problem at all. No need for Rogers up to 2.5 GHz, or maybe even 5 GHz. I don't know what dielectric constant is used for the calculations and simulations. But I suspect you can find this information online. Maybe a PCB vendor will have a helpful article written about it.

Comment: One thing you could do is just design a PCB with a range of trace widths and measure the characteristic impedance using a square wave and oscilloscope, or terminate the all of the traces in 50 Ohms (49.9 Ohm SMT resistor) and measure the reflection with an oscilloscope or something like that. Whichever trace has the smallest reflection is the closest to 50 Ohms. The basic rule of thumb is that the trace width should be double the height above the ground plane for 50 Ohms. So a 10 mil trace with a 5 mil dielctric will be about 50 Ohms. This is for microstrip.

Comment: If you don't have a fast oscilloscope you will need a very big circuit board. LOL.

Comment: My fastest scope is 500MHz, so I guess I'm out of luck, well I should try and see...

Comment: You can try it. That is pretty fast. What is the smallest time division?

Comment: If I recall correctly is 0.5nV / div

Comment: The problem with doing this to avoid specifying a high performance material is that your vendor might use a totally different "FR-4" material on your next order, invalidating your measurement. If you really need the performance you'll get by measuring the Dk of your material, you need to be able to specify a specific material when you go to build the "real" circuit. In which case you ought to be able to get the datasheet for that material and read the Dk without having to do an experiment.

Comment: If you need 50 Ohms, you can just specify that in the fab drawing for the PCB and say traces with 0.11mm width on layer 1 must be 50 Ohms, +/- 5 Ohms. This is called a "controlled impedance board." The coupons are used to keep the PCB fab honest and provide an objective way to resolve disputes.

Comment: @ThePhoton, I stated in one of my comments that this will be used for educational purposes, so no need to worry about mass production. I have never seen a datasheet of an FR-4 stating the hi-freq permitivity (or at any frequency for that matter), in fact most of the time there is no data sheet. Im using MG Chemicals Pre-sensitized boards, no data sheet to be found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, this is a common way to measure the dielectric constant of materials. I would suggest 'calibrating' your leads, and/or using a 4-wire measurement (provided your LCR meter supports this).

You do need to watch out though: the capacitance of two 10 cm x 10 cm squares on 1.6mm thick FR4 (assuming permittivity of about 4) is about on the order of 0.2 nF, so you need to be carefull with your setup to avoid your measurement being ruined by parasitic capacitance.

Other methods that can be used are making transmission lines (but using a transmission line requires a lot of expertise and precision to get anything useful - you really need to take into account your strip width and profile after etching to get correct results).

A method I've used with some success is by making resonators (usually ring resonators or ground-slot resonators). By matching the measured resonator performance to simulations you can get good results (again, provided you can 'calibrate out' etching effects).

Comment: All the answers in the comments were good but you were the only who actually posted an answer, my meter is a Keysight handheld meter, I don't think it allows 4 wire measurements, i've seen kits on eBay for LCR meters that go up to 700KHz, I should try that aswell and report back.

Comment: @Joren Vaes - why do you need to "calibrate out" etching effects? A ring resonator resonates at the same frequency regardless of the characteristic impedance (because a change in impedance does not change the circumferential length of the ring). If your ring resonator transmission line is off 50 ohms, it makes no difference. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

If you really want high frequency information, then access/find/borrow/rent a standard Hewlett Packard Network Analyzer, which will give you loss and delay.

These machines by default work to 3,000 MHz.

For stable measurements, you'll need to work not with WIRES, but with SMA screw_on coaxial connectors.

And to minimize reflections between the SMA and your PCB, use edge_mount "transition" connectors. Avoid the bulk-head versions.

The HP/Agilent/Keysight machines are very durable. I suspect any VNA that reaches 3,000MHz (where FR-4 becomes quite lossy) and with power level well above the thermal noise floor of 50 ohms in 100,000 cycle bandwidth (-120 dBm) will work fine.

Comment: I have one of those PC based VNAs,  it goes up to 3GHz, can it be done with one of those?